# Updating a dataframe from another one does not work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have used the following approach many times and it works fine when one wants to update values in one dataframe from another dataframe. However, I have two dataframes that don't want to work. Below are the steps I follow. I can not figure out why this does not work. What am I missing? Can someone maybe point me to possible causes I could investigate:

Original value for "mydate" is 'not found' in df:

```
print(df.loc[df.FileName == '100212']['mydate'])
Out:
406    'not found'
Name: mydate, dtype: object
```

My "new date" value from lookup df1 is '10-2-1997'

```
print(df1.loc[df1.FileName == '100212']['new date']
Out:
2766    10-2-1997
Name: new date, dtype: object
```

The following should update "mydate" in df with "new date" in df1:

```
df.loc[df.FileName.isin(df1.FileName), ['mydate']] = df1['new date']
```

But instead of '10-2-1997' I get 'NaN':

```
print(df.loc[df.FileName == '100212']['mydate'])
Out:
406    'NaN'
Name: mydate, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Series assignment is performed **by index**. But indices don't align between your two dataframes. You can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a series instead:

```
series_map = df1.set_index('FileName')['new date']
df['mydate'] = df['FileName'].map(series_map).fillna(df['mydate'])
```

Using `fillna` afterwards ensures `df['mydate']` remains unchanged when filenames are *not* common between the two dataframes.

Comment: No problem, at 15 reputation you now have the [privilege to upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) answers that helped :).